# Java- jpanel.removeAll no me quita los componentes

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Mi problema es que creo unos JPanels con unos botones dentro. Al pulsar un botón hago un removeAll, pero no se limpia la ventana, sino que debo mover un poco el scroll bar para que se me borre todo, es como que no se está actualizando.

```
 public void limpia() {   //En toria esto debería dejar limpio el JPanel pero no lo hace
    jpActivitiesAll.removeAll();
    jpActivitiesAll.validate();
}


@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case "SHOWALL": 

                break;

            case "SHOWIN": //Es un boton de la interficie el cual funciona correctamente

                this.model.obteProximesActivitats();
                this.vista.limpia();
```

Answer (score 0):

He visto que si añado un revalidate() despúes del removeAll funciona y se limpia el contenido.

```
public void limpia() {
        jpActivitiesAll.removeAll();
        //jpActivitiesAll.validate();
        jpActivitiesAll.revalidate(); //Parece ser que esto recarga la ventana
    }
```

Pregunta aparentemente solucionada. Si alguien puede aportar algo sería genial.

Answer (score 0):

Según tengo entendido, `validate()` no te marca el componente que has eliminado como no valido, sino que directamente hace las modificaciones encima y es posible que se sobre escriban los componentes del panel. En cambio `revalidate()` lo que hace es marcar los antiguos componentes como no validos y vuelve a realizar el diseño del panel. Es posible que aunque haga el diseño no te lo dibuje en el panel/ventana. Es por ello que debes usar después `repaint()`.

Para que comprendas, cuando eliminas un componente lo que se hace es:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
validate;
```

En ese orden, normalmente con usar los dos primeros sobra, pero en casos raros usa los tres.